# Passing parameters to BsonSerializer attribiute in mongoDB c# driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, encryption, attributes

I have a C# class which looks something like this:

```
public class Transaction : IEquatable<Transaction>
 {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid id;

        [BsonElement("text")]
        [BsonSerializer(typeof(TextSerializer))]
        public string texy;

        [BsonElement("departmentid")]
        public Guid departmentId;
}
```

And I have a deserializer for the text which looks something like this:

```
public class TextSerializer : SerializerBase<string> // IBsonSerializer<JObject>
{
    public override string Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var myBSONDoc = BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(context);
        return myBSONDoc.ToString();
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, string value)
    {
        var myBSONDoc = MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Parse(value);
        BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Serialize(context, myBSONDoc);
    }
}
```

Now I want to decrypt and encrypt the **text** field whenever I get/set the field on mongo, using the **departmentId** field. Is it possible to get the departmentId value inside the Serialize and Deserialize methods? Or can you think of a different way I can do it (considering that in my real data I have numerous fields on which I want to apply the encryption)

Comment: by encryption, you mean csfle https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/security/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/?

Comment: Not exactly, I have thousands of departments on my app and I want a different encryption key for each department. I already have a key and encrypt/decrypt functions, I'm just looking for the best way to encrypt and decrypt the fields whenever I set/get them on mongo

Comment: 1. I would recommend using a default CSFLE encryption (but it won't give you a way to work with departmentId (`I want a different encryption key` - in this case you will be responsible for safety, AFAIK csfle allows to do the same thing without taking a risk)). 2. You created a serializer for a field that you marked by `BsonSerializerAttribute`. In this serializer you have access only to this field itself. If you need to get access to some/all fields of the class, you should create a serializer for this class itself